# Meteor - React - Stripe: how to import Stripe

Tags: reactjs, meteor, stripe-payments

In a Meteor/React app I need to import Stripe from mrgalaxy:stripe. I tried:

```
import { Stripe }  from 'meteor/mrgalaxy:stripe';
```

but it returns:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPublishableKey' of undefined
```

In the server folder I created stripe.js file where added the following:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Stripe }  from 'meteor/mrgalaxy:stripe';

Meteor.startup(function(){
  Stripe.setPublishableKey(Meteor.settings.public.StripePub);
});
```

Comment: This package uses an outdated versions of the api and the npm package. Since you can now directly use npm packages and add the script declarations to your `<head>` template.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this test that's in the github repository where there is no import statement

```
Tinytest.add('Stripe client is available', function(test){
  test.isTrue(Stripe != null);
});
```

I'm guessing that including the package just adds a Stripe variable to the global scope.

The stripe_client.html page, that appears to be the only client code in the package, just contains the following html snippet.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
</head>
```

Thus, I think your import is just overriding the global variable. Have you tried removing your import statement? (Please forgive my almost total ignorance of meteor - I may be way off base here).

Comment: when I remove import then it gives me "ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined"

Comment: I've been assuming that https://github.com/tyler-johnson/stripe-meteor/ is the github repository for the package you're trying to use. After digging around a little, it appears this file https://github.com/tyler-johnson/stripe-meteor/blob/master/package.js is what tells meteor how to handle the package. It looks like it may be calling `api.export('STRIPEMETEOR')`, so... maybe try using import { STRIPEMETEOR } ?

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was adding this package "stripe": "^4.9.0" into package.json in addition to mrgalaxy:stripe in .meteor/packages